# A question about The Prestige

Tags: plot-explanation, the-prestige

Assuming Bale twin #1 is the bad-ish one who ties the fatal knot and twin #2 is the meek and gentler one and that Angier met twin #2 both the times when he wanted to know which knot had been tied, why didn't twin #2 lie to Angier?

It's not as if he has sworn to tell the truth throughout his life. Why not tell him he tied the simple knot instead of giving him an annoying and obviously impossible 'I don't know'.

Comment: We don't know if it was his twin who made the knot - Borden could genuinely not remember what he made and  Angier was so angry that he wouldn't believe him no matter what he'd say

Comment: The twin who allegedly tied the knot always denied it. The other twin said he doesn't know (because he doesn't). This question is never answered. At best, we have the actual twin (i.e. the one who allegedly tied the knot) denying it; and there are no other witnesses.

Comment: _"instead of giving him an annoying and obviously impossible 'I don't know'"_ The twin who says he doesn't know **genuinely doesn't know**, because he wasn't the one on stage that night. He's not trying to stonewall Angier, he's genuinely revealing that he cannot guarantee what his twin brother did or didn't do. He is so genuinely distraught by her death that this is the closest he ever gets to revealing his twin secret. If he did tell Angier he tied the simple knot, he'd be condemning himself and his twin brother on nothing more than an unproven suspicion - which is significantly worse.